# OpenLayers 3 in Qooxdoo Mobile App

Tags: qooxdoo, openlayers-3

In preparation for the upcoming OpenLayers 3 release, I tried to get the basic map example  to work in a Qooxdoo mobile app.

I used the Qooxdoo mobileshowcase demo map as a starting point, but after many hours of trying I cannot get the map to appear.

For brevity, I included the ol3 css

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ol3js.org/en/master/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
```

I left the whole Maps.js class the same except replaced the mapUri with the OL3 one:

```
_mapUri : "http://ol3js.org/en/master/build/ol.js",
```

and then replaced _loadMapLibrary with:

```
  _loadMapLibrary : function() {
      var req = new qx.bom.request.Script();
      req.onload = function() {
      var map = new ol.Map({
          target: 'osmMap',
          layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
            })
          ],
          view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            zoom: 4
          })
        });
      }.bind(this);

      req.open("GET", this._mapUri);
      req.send();
    },
```

it seems like it should work...

Comment: Generally it should work. Maybe I have time to have a look on it.

Comment: @czuendorf - did you ever get a chance to take a look at this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to add these two lines:

```
mapContainer.setId("map");
mapContainer.addCssClass("map");
```

in this override:

```
// overridden
_createScrollContainer : function()
{
  // MapContainer
  var layout = new qx.ui.mobile.layout.VBox().set(
  {
    alignX : "center",
    alignY : "middle"
  });
  var mapContainer = new qx.ui.mobile.container.Composite(layout);
  mapContainer.setId("map");
  mapContainer.addCssClass("map");
  return mapContainer;
},
```